# Merging 1m DEM to 30m DEM?

Tags: qgis, dem

I have a base 30 m.Dem . However, i also have 1m Dem for an area of interest only. I would like to overlay the 1m Dem on the 30 m Dem meaning the area of interest will have 1m and the rest 30m.

Is that possible?

Comment: What GIS software are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: If you're using ArcGIS you can do this in a Mosaic Dataset, otherwise a virtual raster might be plausible depending on your software.. the concept of both is that the rasters aren't *in the object* but only referenced *by the object* so there is a potential for differing cell sizes (but your software may not like that). The only other way I know of is to resample the 30m DEM to 1m and mosaic.

Comment: Hi, tq for your reply. Im using Qgis. Ive tired using Raster - miscellanious - merge and I get the following error " Free disk space available is 854369820672 bytes, whereas 10867546031584 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to. There is no option to check the CHECK DISK FREE SPACE, so hoping you would be able to point me to the right direction

Comment: im trying the virtual raster now

Answer (score 3):

A raster file cannot have multiple resolutions. So if you want a mosaic of 30m and 1m resolution raster, you will need to build a 1 m resolution raster. Over a large area, this might be huge (1 m resolution is 900 times larger than 30m resolution), and based on your comments it is approximately 1 Tb in your case (large but manageable).

Here are some tips to solve your problem, but more details about the purpose of the analysis would help you select the best option :

Conceptual solution: use TIN instead of raster, because TIN have irregular sizes

Storage solution : By default, your DEM will be in floating points, but do you need it ? You could divide the size by 2 or 4 if you could store it in int16 or in Bytes. Storing in Bytes is probably too coarse for a DEM, but you could multiply your heigth by 10 and store it in uint16 (just be careful if you have negative elevation (e.g. Dead Sea, then use int16 instead of uint16) or mountains above 6500 m (e.g Everest, then shift your elevation by 3000m). Another solution is to make a compromise: using a 2 meter final resolution help you dividind the size of your dataset by 4. Finally, make sure that you also tick the advanced parameters and add a compression, which would help reducing the size of your dataset.

Virtual file solution: building a vrt will make sure that you don't occupy too much disk space. The resampling to one meter could be done on the fly with a -r cubic option. A simple trick if your 1 m raster is a rectangle in the middile of your 30 rasters is to create 4 vrts at 30 m that surround your 1 m raster, the merge those four 30m vrt's with the 1m vrt (-tr 1 1 in the options to set the final resolution at 1 meter)